# TLS error "TLS_DHE_RSA" in ev ssl certificate

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2, starttls, tls1.3

Install an EV ssl certificate on the company's website, but I get these "errors" although they are not so drastic I want to solve it, could you help me with this

error:

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv6s7.jpg)

Comment: Configure the used server accordingly to not provide these ciphers. As you have not mention any details on your set-up we can not help you any further.

Comment: The configuration is by default, the certificate is RSA CA G2